# Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab installation error MATLAB R2010b

Tags: matlab, bayesian-networks

I am getting an error when try to test [Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/), I am doing the same as the installation shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/wiki/HowToInstall) but get errors (I have Matlab R2010b):

```
>> cd 'C:\MATLAB\R2010b\FullBNT-1.0.4'
>> addpath(genpathKPM(pwd))
Warning: Function C:\MATLAB\R2010b\FullBNT-1.0.4\KPMtools\assert.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential
name conflict. 
> In path at 110
  In addpath at 87
Warning: Function C:\MATLAB\R2010b\FullBNT-1.0.4\KPMtools\isscalar.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential
name conflict. 
> In path at 110
  In addpath at 87
Warning: Function C:\MATLAB\R2010b\FullBNT-1.0.4\KPMtools\isvector.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential
name conflict. 
> In path at 110
  In addpath at 87
>> test_BNT

ll =

  1.0e-010 *

   -0.0670    0.1697

cycle 1 lik -51.5585 
cycle 2 lik -45.0863 
cycle 3 lik -42.9953 
??? Undefined function or method 'finite' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> ffa at 71
  elseif ((lik-likbase)<(1+tol)*(oldlik-likbase)|~finite(lik))

Error in ==> fa1 at 27
[L1, Psi1, LL1] = ffa(X,k,max_iter);

Error in ==> test_BNT at 8
fa1

>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said: Replace calls to the obsolete finite with isfinite
in 
BNT/examples/static/Zoubin/ffa.m and BNT/examples/static/Zoubin/mfa.m

here is a [reference](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/wiki/HowToInstall)

Answer (score 0):

Using newer versions > 7.8
 - Replace calls to the obsolete `finite` with `isfinite`
   in
  `BNT/examples/static/Zoubin/ffa.m and BNT/examples/static/Zoubin/mfa.m`

so `test_BNT` will now work.